# AttributeError: module 'hyperopt' has no attribute 'uniform'

Tags: python, optimization, hyperopt

I am trying to define a parameter space in hyperopt. However, when I run:

```
import hyperopt as hp
SPACE = {'d1': hp.uniform('d1',-1000000,-0.5),
'd2': hp.uniform('d2',0,1),
'd3': hp.uniform('d3',0,1)}
```

I receive the error in the title. The only thing I found online was that I should try downgrading to networkx 1.11, so in the command prompt I ran:

```
pip install networkx==1.11
```

and it apparently worked, but still no luck with the attribute uniform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct way to import the `hp` part of the [hyperopt](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) module is

```
from hyperopt import hp
```

You have used

```
import hyperopt as hp
```

Answer (score 2):

Hyperopt has inbuilt module `hp` which has the function `uniform` within it

```
import hyperopt.hp as hp
```

and then `hp.uniform` would work fine for you. This works good with `networkx-2.2`.